# Formatting calendar in Linux Terminal

Tags: shell

I have been playing around with the Linux terminal, and here is an odd thing that I am not able to explain. When I type the following command, the calendar turns out formatted in the terminal:

```
echo "$(cal)"
```

However, when I type the same command without quotes, the calendar isn't formatted.

```
echo $(cal)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type `cal` you will get the calendar formatted on several lines.  The man page for `echo` says that it "writes each given STRING to standard output, with a space between each and a newline after the last one." So, what you are seeing when you type `echo $(cal)` is exactly that--each line of the output of `cal` is being treated as a separate string and written to the standard output with a space between each.  When you say `echo "$(cal)"` you are getting the literal value of the output--newlines and all.

This is true of any command that returns string output--try it with `ifconfig`.

Hope this helps!